# Is there a way to use an Android Mobile as a focusing screen for Nikon D800?

Tags: macro, nikon-d800

I want to use Android Mobile as a focusing screen. It is very difficult to focus as I am macro photographer. Please suggest some ideas, solutions, or tips..?

I own a Nikon D800 and all lenses and accessories.

Comment: I don't want to put this in as an answer, because I hope someone has better news, but it seems to get basic wireless connectivity out of a D800 you need not one, but two adapters, totalling about $1000 - the UT-1 and the WT5a. Unless you fancy hacking a WU-1a instead - https://petapixel.com/2012/11/09/hacker-gets-nikon-d800-to-play-nice-with-the-wu-1a-wireless-mobile-adapter/ Nikon themselves don't list the D800 in their wireless app compatibility list - https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/eu/BV_article?articleNo=000042315&lang=en_GB&setRedirect=true#dslr

Answer (score 2):

You may plug it into the Android device via USB (right cable or adapter USB-A to your mobile USB port).  Then install a camera control app, like Camera connect & control or Helicon.
The D800 is listed as supported by those, but check well if live view actually works for your model.
The Nikon's control app, Snapbridge, officially doesn't support the D800.

You may also try with the HDMI camera output: get a HDMI to USB adapter, plug it on the android and get some app "Android as USB monitor". You should see the live view, but cannot control the camera.